# How can I use jQuery loop variable to start at 2 while maintaining field removal option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, variables, increment

I found this snippet to add additional fields to a form. Works great. If you may, please let me know how I can have the added fields start at 2 while also maintaining the option to remove it. While i = 2 does work, I have not figured out what's needed for the option to add/remove said fields accordingly. Thank you for your time.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 1;
  $('#add').click(function() {
    if (i <= 7) {
      $('#dynamic_field').append('<div class="add-row" id="row' + i + '"><label" for="number_' + i + '">Number ' + i + '</label><input type="text" name="number_' + i + '" value=""></div>')
      i++;
      $('.btn-remove').removeClass('hidden');
    }
  });
  $(document).on('click', '.btn-remove', function() {
    var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
    i--;
    $('#row' + $('#dynamic_field div').length).remove();
    if (i<=1) {
      $('.btn-remove').addClass('hidden');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="add" class="btn-add">Add Another Number</button>   <button type="button" class="btn-remove hidden">Remove last</button>
<div id="dynamic_field"></div>
```

Comment: What do you mean with "start at 2"? You mean the first label should be `Number 2`? Anything else? BTW, giving elements an id that has an incremental number is not very useful. If you need to access elements by number, just get the collection of those elements and select by index (or use a CSS selector). No need for `id` attributes with numbers.

Comment: Thank you for such a quick reply. The visible field can be construed as field 1 with the proceeding "added" fields starting with 2 then 3, 4... ect. With the increment dynamically added to the field name, I can then output each variable separately.

Comment: *"The visible field"*: So you want the first field to be always there, and not to be removable?

Comment: Technically that could work if the number "1" isn't displayed on the "default" field. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is being made unnecessarily complicated by the use of `id` attributes which you generate at runtime.

You can completely avoid the need to do this by using the same content in each row, which you can store in a `template` element. Note that this template content uses no `id`, but the same `class` instead, and also that the `label` wraps the `input` so no `for` attribute is required.

You can then simply get the number of existing rows in the DOM to calculate the next number to display. Also, as the 'remove' button only targets the last row you can select it directly with `.row:last`.

Here's a working example with all these changes implemented:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  let maxRows = 7;
  let rowTemplate = $('#row-template').html();
  let $container = $('#dynamic_field');

  $('#add').on('click', () => {
    let rowCount = $('.row').length;
    if (rowCount >= maxRows)
      return;
      
    let $row = $(rowTemplate).appendTo($container);
    $row.find('span').text(rowCount += 2);
    $('.btn-remove').removeClass('hidden');
  });
  
  $(document).on('click', '.btn-remove', () => $('.row:last').remove());
});
```

```css
.hidden { 
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="add" class="btn-add">Add Another Number</button> 
<button type="button" class="btn-remove hidden">Remove last</button>
<div id="dynamic_field"></div>

<template id="row-template">
  <div class="row">
    <label>
      Number <span></span>
      <input type="text" name="number[]" value="" />
    </label>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. It's perhaps a nit-pick due to the default field. It makes more sense to give numbers to the added fields beginning with "2" (Default is assumed 1, Add 2, Add 3 ect. Thanks again.

Comment: Of course, I missed that. Edited to correct by adding 2 to the length property

Comment: I can't thank you enough. This solution is PERFECT. You sir, are a golden God!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to keep a count yourself

```js
$(function() {
  const $container = $("#dynamic_field");
  let count = $container.children().length;
  $('.btn-remove').toggle(count > 1);

  $('#add').click(function() {
    let count = $container.children().length;
    if (count < 7) {
      $('#dynamic_field').append(`<div class="add-row" id="row$(count)"><label" for="number_${count}">Number ${count+1}</label><input type="text" name="number_${count}" value=""></div>`);
      count++;
    }
    $('.btn-remove').toggle(count > 0);
  });
  $(document).on('click', '.btn-remove', function() {
    const $children = $container.children();
    $children.last().remove();
    let count = $children.length;
    console.log(count)
    $(this).toggle(count > 1);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="add" class="btn-add">Add Another Number</button> <button type="button" class="btn-remove hidden">Remove last</button>

<div id="dynamic_field"></div>
```

Also You could CLONE an existing row

```js
$(function() {
  const $container = $("#dynamic_field");
  const getCount = () => $container.find(".add-row").length;  
  $('.btn-remove').toggle(getCount() > 1);

  $('#add').click(function() {
    let count = getCount();
    if (count < 7) {
      const $cloneDiv =  $container.children().first().clone().appendTo($container);
      $cloneDiv.find("input").val("").attr("name",`number${count+1}`);
      $cloneDiv.find("label").text(`Number ${count+1}`);
    }
    $('.btn-remove').toggle(count > 0);
  });
  $(document).on('click', '.btn-remove', function() {
    $container.find(".add-row").last().remove();
    let count = getCount()
    console.log(count)
    $(this).toggle(count > 1);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="add" class="btn-add">Add Another Number</button> <button type="button" class="btn-remove hidden">Remove last</button>

<div id="dynamic_field">
  <div class="add-row" id="1">
    <label for="number_1">Number 1</label><input type="text " name="number_1 " value="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. For reasons posted above, I was hoping to start the count at 2.

Comment: As you can see, I add one to count to get one. If you want two, then do `let count = $container.children().length+1;`